# How to keep ASP.NET running

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

So here is my case, I want to create a web application using ASP.Net, 
I have a simple UI that has two text boxes and a button called "RUN"
the two text boxes are for first and last name 
a user can enter values and click run

I have a function that access Mongo Database and get all the documents where the first and last name match what the user have asked for
then I write the result to an output file "Excel sheet" 
then that "mongo" function returns to the "Button_Click" function 
which goes to disk and upload that excel sheet and give the user a save "window" so the user can download the file.
I have only tested this on my local machine and seems to be working fine, now I am not sure how that is going to work when I move to a different machine. 
but that is not my question,

**The question is**, I want to add a third text box where the user can enter a location where he/she wants excel file to be dumped. that can be on a third server that is accessible from client and server "where web app is hosted". 
the reason is that some queries can take up to 15 or 20 minutes and the user does not want his/her web browser to be running the whole time. so after specifying the info needed "firstName, LastName" along with the location where the excel file is going to be saved, he can click run and close the web browser. the program will run **in the background I am assuming**  and dump the excel file to the specified location and send an email to the user notifying that the file is ready and was copied to the desired location so he/she can check it later on.
Is this doable? and how will the program be running when the user has closed his/her browser ?? do I need two different projects ?

Comment: After the user clicks on the run button your server will continue with the process until it finishes, the server does not know and doesn't care if the user is waiting or has closed his browser.

Comment: At least you can take some time to write a nice readable looking question. a Good question can help you also to find the answer by your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you need to do an asynchronous call to some function on your server to do the work for you without letting the user wait on browser. For this you can write a **WCF service with asynchronous service operation** .The WCF service will be hosted under a windows service or IIS on a server, the implementation will include the functionality you want ( such as querying the db, creating excel file, writing the file on server and sending email), all these should go inside the WCF service implementation, and from ASP.NET you just click the button, you will grab the user input and call your asynchronous function asynchronously that is defined in your WCF service (via the contract that you will provide)

Read this for 
[How to: Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of long running process in ASP.Net, we normally use background task such as [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

You might want to read [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).